# syncing 2 arrays into another (nodal connectivity)

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create a point/nodal connectivity array from an array of point/nodes.

I want to create an Array, Array C (8 columns), from two other Arrays A and B. Array A is a 2 column array and Array B is a 4 column array.

Example is as follows. Array A is a series of points/nodes with x and y coordinates. Each row of the array corresponds to a specific point/node number eg

```
Array A = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]....[xn,yn]]
```

where `x1`, `y1` represent `x` and `y` coordinates of point/node 1 and so on.

Array `B` is the connectivity of these nodes to make up a specific polygon shape.

```
Array B = [[1, 2, 193, 192],[3, 4, 194, 193], [5, 6, 195, 194]...........]
```

where the numbers in each row of the array represent the points/node numbers from Array `A`.

I want like to create an array C that takes in the x and y coordinates from Array A and plugs them into Array B. i.e splits the node number into x and y coordinates of that node and converts from 4 columns to 8 columns.

The 8 column Array C should take on the following form:

```
Array C = [[x1,y1,x2,y2,x193,y193,x192,y192].......]
```

where `xn,yn` represent the `x` and `y` coordinates from the node number in Array A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hint you can use a nested list comprehension for this task, for example :

```
>>> Array_A = [['x1','y1'],['x2','y2'],['x3','y3'],['x4','y4'],['x5','y5'],['x6','y6'],['x7','y7'],['x8','y8'],['x9','y9']] 
>>> Array_B = [[1, 2, 9],[3, 4, 7], [5,6,8]]
>>> [[j for i,j in enumerate(Array_A,1) if i in indices] for indices in Array_B]
[[['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2'], ['x9', 'y9']], [['x3', 'y3'], ['x4', 'y4'], ['x7', 'y7']], [['x5', 'y5'], ['x6', 'y6'], ['x8', 'y8']]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are confident `A` and `B` have the same number of elements, you could do:

```
A = [
        ['x1', 'y1'],
        ['x2', 'y2'],
]

B = [
        [1, 2, 193, 192],
        [3, 4, 194, 193],
]

C = [cols+B[i] for i, cols in enumerate(A)]

# gives: [['x1', 'y1', 1, 2, 193, 192], ['x2', 'y2', 3, 4, 194, 193]]
```

Note sure if it's the result you wanted though, i'll correct if needed.